# ModalPopupExtender won't reload iframe in updatepanel on second call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe

My page is loading a separate aspx page for user input into an iframe within an UpdatePanel contained within a ModalPopupExtender. This works fine but when I try to register the btnOK asp:button using GetPostBackEventReference, so that I can do a proper call back after the ModalPopupExtender closes from the user pressing the OK button (within the iframe), for some reason I'm not able to reopen the iframe (say if the user want's to do another input of the same kind i.e. enter multiple activities in this case). The issue that happens is that the ModalPopupExtender shadow appears, but the iframe never loads fully within it.

If I use `__doPostBack('<%=btnOK .ClientID%>','OnClick');` instead of GetPostBackEventReference, I'm able to do a second call, but my C# event handler for the button wont fire ... rather I just get a PostBack only. I'm guessing since I get a full PostBack, something resets the page and everything starts over.

Any Idea how I can fix this ?

To give a bit of background of what I'm trying to do: The page is supposed to show content to the user while loading other pages into iframes and ModalPopupExtenders in order to keep the page smaller and separate input from output. With this in mind, I need to be able to control the flow and do proper call-backs when necessary.

**Code containing ModalPopupExtender**:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head_Obudget" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.CssClass_btnNewActivity').click(function () {
            $('#frameInsertActivity').attr('src', 'InputForms/InsertActivity.aspx');
        });
    });
    function InsertActivity_Done() {
        <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnOK, String.Empty) %>;
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Obudget" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNewActivity" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOK" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender 
            BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"
            ID="mpeNewActivity" 
            runat="server"
            PopupControlID="divNewActivity" 
            TargetControlID="btnNewActivity"
            OkControlID="btnOK"
            CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
            DropShadow="true">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:button id="btnNewActivity" runat="server" CssClass="CssClass_btnNewActivity" text="New Activity" />
        <div id="divNewActivity">
            <iframe id="frameInsertActivity" width="500" height="100" frameBorder="0">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="popup_Buttons"style="display: none;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" OnClick="btnOK_Click" OnClientClick="InsertActivity_Done();" CssClass="CSS_Class_btnOK" />
            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code for iframe**:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head_Empty" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    body{background:white;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function okay() {
        $(window.parent.document).find('.CSS_Class_btnOK').click();
    }
    function cancel() {
        window.parent.document.getElementById('btnCancel').click();
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Empty" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
            New Activity:
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name: <asp:TextBox ID="tbNewActivityName" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNewActivityName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbNewActivityName" ValidationGroup="VG_NewActivity" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="popup_Buttons">
                <asp:Button ID="btnInsertNewActivity" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnInsertNewActivity_Click" ValidationGroup="VG_NewActivity" />
                <input id="btnCancel" onclick="cancel();" type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the issue was: The button that opens the ModalPopupExtender, also executes jQuery on click event to wire up the iframe's 'src' attribute.

I need to use a delegated event handler to process events from descendant elements to allow me to find this button again after having returned from the iframe's first execution

... the code now looks and works as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.CssClass_btnNewActivity', function () {
            $('#frameInsertActivity').attr('src', 'InputForms/InsertActivity.aspx');
        });
```

...as opposed to this, which didn't work:

```
$('.CssClass_btnNewActivity').click(function () {
        $('#frameInsertActivity').attr('src', 'InputForms/InsertActivity.aspx');
    });
```

... I always forget about this =]